# Finding the probability of a type II error for a poisson distribution

Tags: type-i-and-ii-errors

A poisson distribution is being tested with the hypothesis

H0: λ = 1.7 and H1: λ ≠ 1.7

The true value of the mean is 2.3. For the significant level 10% calculate:

a )The critical region

b) The probability of a type II error

c) The power

just need help with part a, I used a poisson cumulative distribution, with a lower boundary of 4, an upper boundary of  100000000 and λ = 1.7 to receive the following values.

P(X ≥ 3) = 0.24277679

P(X ≥ 4) = 0.09318943

P(X ≥ 5) = 0.0296148

Therefore, I said that the critical region was X ≥ 4 because P(X ≥ 4) < 0.1, however, the textbook says the critical region was X ≥ 5. Am I correct, or have I missed something?

Comment: Okay, I have spotted my mistake, it is a two-tailed test so P(X ≥ 5) < 0.05 hence that is the critical region. However, is the reason why that is the only value because X ≥ 0 for the poisson distribution and P(X = 0) = 0.18268352, which is > than 0.05??

Comment: If you use a two sided test you need two values, an upper and lower limit, sometimes the lower limit can be pretty large, like in this case, but you still need to report a value and since 0 is the smallest value then this is the lower bound.